# read.demogdata in R demography package message length

Tags: r

i am using R and the package demography in a step of a project in my studies but i have a problem that why i am coming to you hopping that someone will help me because i spent more than  2 weeks on it without founf=ding a solution....
when i am using it say that i have different length  i will explain in detail :
1)to see where is the problem i tried to read every data a part using the code below :

```
install.packages("demography")
library(demography)
AA <- read.table("Death.txt", header = TRUE)
BB <- read.table("Exposure.txt", header = TRUE)
```

**#i have 6105 observations for both of them 
and for data i put them in the links**

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1v7TtjdyTbMdcaIE_PHeMKbd6ozdMmn1N

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1hMWxq5TYGhnacxdeDYfpnt5jgJdjgTfe

2) but when i am using the package demography it read like 6103 by using the code :

```
Be <- read.demogdata("Death.txt", "Exposure.txt",type="mortality", label="Belgium")
```

then i have the messages :
Warning messages:

1: In matrix(tmp1[, i + 2], nrow = m, ncol = n) :
  data length [6103] is not a sub-multiple or multiple of the number of rows [111]

2: In matrix(tmp1[, i + 2], nrow = m, ncol = n) :
  data length [6103] is not a sub-multiple or multiple of the number of rows [111]

3: In matrix(tmp1[, i + 2], nrow = m, ncol = n) :
  data length [6103] is not a sub-multiple or multiple of the number of rows [111]

4: In read.demogdata("Death.txt", "Exposure.txt", type = "mortality",  :
  Population names different from rates names

5: In matrix(tmp2[, i + 2], nrow = m, ncol = n) :
  data length [6103] is not a sub-multiple or multiple of the number of rows [111]

6: In matrix(tmp2[, i + 2], nrow = m, ncol = n) :
  data length [6103] is not a sub-multiple or multiple of the number of rows [111]

7: In matrix(tmp2[, i + 2], nrow = m, ncol = n) :
  data length [6103] is not a sub-multiple or multiple of the number of rows [111]

thanks in advance for how will help me with this .

Answer (score 0):

Probably it is a little bit late and I hope you already find the solution to that. But in case you haven't, do the following:

1. Make sure that you (really) have the same number of rows in both of your files.
2. Make sure that you (really) have the same names for your columns.
3. If you do, and still doesn´t work, check the read.demogdata. The function contains two parameters: "skip" and "popskip". If the name of tour columns is on the first row of your .txt files set both parameters to zero:

```
    Be <- read.demogdata("Death.txt", "Exposure.txt",type="mortality",
 label="Belgium", skip=0, popskip=0)
```

Hope it works!